# Using BBCodes...Parse HTML or remove it altogether? (XSS/PHP)

Tags: php, html, xss, wysiwyg, bbcode

I'm creating a mini-forum in PHP and I want to allow user posts with limited text formatting and embedding images, but I want to do it securely (XSS-wise) and I was wondering what's the most optimal approach of the ones below.

1) Strip all HTML tags from user input, and replace the WYSIWYG editor's controls with BBCode. Is strip_tags sufficient for this?

2) Allow HTML input through the WYSIWYG, but use a parser to convert the output from HTML to BBCode. Can anyone recommend a secure BBCode parser for this?

Any other ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parse or strip HTML to be secure. Just run everything through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before you print it and you are safe.

In addition, this is orthogonal to using BBcode. You can have your editor generate BBcode for formatting, and `htmlspecialchars` will not mess with it in any way.

Comment: This seems like the route I'm going to take, thanks. One last question, I've seen many recommend htmlentities over htmlspecialchars, is it actually more secure?

Comment: @Bachx: No. Personally I don't see a compelling use case for `htmlentities` at all, except helping people who don't handle encodings correctly kind of trudge along.